# How to extract typescript mongoose/typegoose schema

Tags: typescript, generics, mongoose, metaprogramming, typegoose

Here a declared schema

```js
class AccountSchema;
```

Here a declared model

```js
const AccountClass: Model<AccountSchema & Document>;
class Account extends AccountClass;
```

Why doesn't this work?

```js
type ExtractSchema<T extends Model<Document>> = T extends Model<infer D & Document> ? D : never;
class Service<T extends Model<ExtractSchema<T> & Document>> {
  public async getSchema(): ExtractSchema<T>;
}
class AccountService extends Service<typeof Account> {
  public test() {
   [ERROR: this.getSchema() returns never]
   this.getSchema()
  }
}
```

What is the best way to extract out the schema using generics and is there any way to not include javascript getter and setter function, just plain field?

Answer (score 0):

When you use typegoose or mongoose the following should work

```
class Service<T extends Model<ExtractSchema<T> & Document>> {
  public async getSchema(): ExtractSchema<T> {
   return this.schema; 
  }
}
```

`this.schema` will return the schema when the function is called from an document, otherwise you will need to set the `static` word to make it an static function (to be called from the model)

as for types, you should use `mongoose.Schema<typeof YourClass>` as the return type for `getSchema` otherwise the return type will be an model (which it isnt at runtime)